# why return [object Object] in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, database, express, ejs

I am currently adding a new product on the admin side, then I want to display the user's performed action in the console.log but it returns [object Object], I am currently having a problem in my code, can someone help me with my problem?

```
exports.postFlower = (req,res,next) => {

            const stock = new Stocks ({
                user: req.session.user._id,
                flowerName: req.body.flowerName,
                quantity: req.body.quantity 
            })
            stock.save((err, stock) => {
                if(stock){
                    console.log('Created flower for user: ' + req.session.user)
                    res.redirect('flowers-in-stock')
                }
            })
    
        }
```

```
Created flower for user: [object Object]
```

Maybe this could help in my problem

```
exports.postLoginForm = (req,res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);
    User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).exec((err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(400).json({ message: err })

        if(user){
            if(user.password==req.body.password && user.role === 'admin'){
                //console.log("Done Login");
                console.log('admin login')
                req.session.isAdmin = true;
                req.session.user = {user};
                
                console.log(user)
                res.send({"Success":"Success!"});
                
            }else if(user.password==req.body.password && user.role === 'assistant'){
                console.log('assistant login')

                req.session.isAdmin = true;
                req.session.user = {user};
                
                console.log(user)
                res.send({"Success":"Success!"});

            } else{
                res.send({"Success":"Password is incorrect. Please try again."});
            }
        }else{
            res.send({"Success":"The email is not registered. Please try again."});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Because it's correct. What specifically are you confused about? Do you want to see what the object contains in your console.log? Then you can `console.log('Created flower for user: ' + JSON.stringify(req.session.user,null,2))` or better yet, use the object printing feature in node's `console.log` by not converting that object into a string: `console.log('Created flower for user: ', req.session.user)` (note that I'm using a comma instead of `+`)

Comment: Basically the answer to your question of why does it print `[Object object]` is because it is the correct thing to print and there is nothing wrong with your code and apart from you being confused you have zero problems you need to fix with your code.

Comment: This `req.session.user = {user};` looks like a typo, it creates an extra wrapper object with the `user` property and puts `user` object in the property. That's an extra property you possibly don't need. Just put your object in the session, `req.session.user = user;`

Comment: Thank you with your suggestions. I able to understand why it prints [object Object]. I just want to display the user that perform in adding the product but it is working now. Thank you with your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.session.user` is an object and you are trying to concatenate it to a string, which is causing JS to convert the object to a string, resulting in "[object Object]".

Use smth like this:

```
console.log(`Created flower for user: ${req.session.user.email}`);
```

or this:

```
console.log('Created flower for user: ', ${req.session.user});
```

or even this:

```
console.log(`Created flower for user: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.user)}`);
```

Comment: Thank you! I combined all of your suggestions hehe

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to output an object rather than a user. You could change your code to

```
exports.postFlower = (req,res,next) => {

            const stock = new Stocks ({
                user: req.session.user._id,
                flowerName: req.body.flowerName,
                quantity: req.body.quantity 
            })
            stock.save((err, stock) => {
                if(stock){
                    console.log('Created flower for user: ' + req.session.user._id)
                    res.redirect('flowers-in-stock')
                }
            })
    
        }
```

to log the userid from the user